# Why is Chrome 34/38/28 ranked so high on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics, user-agent

I [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742615/google-analytics-tells-me-that-over-2-of-my-visitors-are-using-chrome-1-or-1-5/24436753#24436753) a while back where Google Analytics was mis-attributing new Samsung user agents to Chrome 1.5 instead of 28. I can't find bug reports or SO questions for this one so thought I'd put it out there.

As of today, Chrome 47.0 has the most usage on my Google Analytics (61%), followed by v48.0 (which just came out this week - 25%). But the next one down is v34.0 (3.3% or 5,600 sessions). Now I'm certain I don't actually have that many users who haven't updated Chrome in 2 years. I'd like to filter them somehow but don't know what to attribute that to. **Any thoughts?** Specifically, does anyone know what browsers they are actually using?

(This also seems to be the case for v38.0 - 3900 users - and 28.0 - 1500 users. I'm certain those are just misinterpretted by Google Analytics.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing a trend here. In our GA data, I'm showing these as the top entries under "Mobile Device Info":

For Chrome v**34.0**:

```
Samsung SM-G900A Samsung Galaxy S5
Samsung SM-G900P Galaxy S5
Samsung SM-N910A Galaxy Note 4
Samsung SCH i545 Galaxy S4
Samsung SM-G900T Samsung Galaxy S5
Samsung SM-N910V Samsung Galaxy Note 4
Samsung SGH-I337 Samsung Galaxy S4
Samsung SM-N910P Galaxy Note 4
Samsung SM-N900V Galaxy Note 3
Samsung SM-G870A Samsung Galaxy S5 Active
```

...for v**38.0**:

```
Samsung SM-G920P Galaxy S6
(not set)
Samsung SM-G920T Galaxy S6
Samsung SM-N920A Galaxy Note 5
Samsung SM-N920P Galaxy Note 5
Samsung SM-N920T Galaxy Note 5
Samsung SM-N920V 4G Galaxy Note 5
Samsung SM-G890A Galaxy S6 Active
Samsung SM-G925T Galaxy S6 Edge
Samsung SM-G925A Galaxy S6 Edge
```

...and for v**28.0**:

```
Samsung SM-N900T Samsung Galaxy Note
Samsung SCH-M919 Galaxy S IV
Samsung SPH-L720T Galaxy S4
Samsung SM-G900T Galaxy S5
Samsung SM-G900A Galaxy S5
Samsung SCH-I337 Galaxy S IV
Samsung SM-G386T Galaxy Avant
Samsung SM-T230NU Galaxy Tab 4 7.0
Samsung SM-G870A Galaxy S5 Active
Samsung SM-G386T1 Galaxy Avant
```

But I still don't know what ACTUAL **browser version** each of these are supposed to have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I have a two guesses:
1. Chrome 34 is the latest version that doesn't require an SSE2 processor, so people on older computers would be stuck with it or forced to jump to a different browser.
2. Google pulled out NPAPI support from Chrome 35+, so anybody using old plugins would have to stay at version 34 and below to use them.

Comment: Oh, #2 is a very good theory. I wonder how many people have manually turned off auto-update for that reason. I have a lot of data showing these are coming from Samsung Galaxy's so it's probably GA misinterpretting those user agents. But there are still several entries from desktops, so those are good reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is probably also due to “Android stock browsers” which often get stuck for years on certain browser versions, claiming to be some old versions of Chrome. This happens because the vendors are providing no longer software updates for old devices and the stock browsers only get updated together with the operating system. For example you could find, thousands of “fresh” old Chrome User-Agents in resent time (“First Seen Date”) in this [User-Agent Searchengine](http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=android%20chrome%20linux%20%22Chrome%2F3%22&include=yes&class=brm&do=desc).